# How to not close MacVim after the last tab is closed?

Tags: macvim, tabbed-user-interface

Can this be done by editing the .vimrc file?

What I need is that after closing all tabs, a new tab is there like notepad++ does.

Comment: Vim quits when no buffer is visible and there's no option to change that.

Comment: How would you be able to quit Vim if you can't close the last buffer/tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be looking for MacVim Preferences, and they are under the MenuBar entitled "MacVim".

*MacVim -> Preferences -> General*

There you'll find settings for what to do on startup, and after the last MacVim window closes. You can decide to automatically open a blank window on startup, and also for when "the last window closes" you can check "Leave MacVim Running".

There doesn't seem to be a setting to *automatically* open a new blank window when the last MacVim window closes, but you can easily hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.